# Angular2:how to use the observable to broadcast event within forEach?

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach

I found when I use the service within forEach,the parameter I send to the service beacome the last one of the circulation.

> I thought it should be the **closure** cause this problem,so I try to use the  anonymous function to solve it,but didn't work

**Pass the obj in Component**

> this function is triggered in `ngOnInit` may cause the problem
>
> when I put this code into a click event,it works fine

```
   for (var y = 0; y < this.model.data.length;y++) {
       if (this.model.data[i].to[x].id === this.model.data[y].id) {
           let obj = {
               selectedItem : this.model.data[i],
               item : this.model.data[y]
           };    
           (function(_obj,a) {
                console.log ('obje in component:');
                console.log (_obj.item.id)    //each obj over here is correct now

                a._drawLineService.drawLine(_obj);
                a._dragLineService.dragLine(_obj.item);
            })(obj,this)                                   
        }
   }
```

**Get the obj in directive**

```
this.subscription = this._drawLineService.drawLine$
   .subscribe(obj => {  
       console.log ('drawLine:')     
       console.log (obj.item.id) //each obj over here become the last one of array                                                                      
   });
```

> I use the **observable** to pass the event and parameter from component to directive

**My service**

```
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core'
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DrawLineService {
  private _drawLine = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  drawLine$ = this._drawLine.asObservable();
  drawLine(item) {
    this._drawLine.next(item);
  }
}
```

**Console result:**

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `var obj=...` to `let obj=...`

`let` define variable to block scope while `var` define variable to function or global scope.

You are actually keep overwriting the `obj` variable with your loop.

Comment: I think this is related to the order of your subscription and your loop. I put up a plunker which works: https://plnkr.co/edit/nR9PL5b8bS5OenZNJNBM?p=preview

Comment: I put it into the `ngOnInit()`  maybe cause this problem,when I use the click event to trigger it ,it works fine,but why? see this plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/alQFlYEFL3G6jvBsUl2s?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/alQFlYEFL3G6jvBsUl2s?p=preview)

Comment: The ngOnInit in the component will get called before the ngOnInit in the idrective, which means when the items get put in the stream(your loop) you haven't subscribe to `drawLine$` yet.

Comment: got it,but how to solve this,when I need to tigger this event at the beginning?

Comment: Use another event instead of ngOnInit (i.e. ngAfterViewInit). Check this one: https://plnkr.co/edit/AlN7m21m7txUTTr87rEF  Check  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html for more lifecycle hooks

Comment: thanks a lot,I use ngAfterViewChecked,and it works well now : )

Comment: why does it cause this problem again after I add a route in this component?

Comment: It all depends on the order that your code get executed. You can set couple break points in your ngAfterViewChecked functions and your subscribe method  to see what is happening first.

Comment: I send the event twice ,and the directive get only once,the last value.I think it should be the  `BehaviorSubject` 's stream,it cancel the first event,after the second event has been called.

Comment: This happens when you subscribe to the stream after all the item get pushed in to the stream.